# Applying Neuralnet and nnet - MultiClass Classification

Tags: r, neural-network, nnet, multiclass-classification

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
source <- c('A','B','C','C','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D', 'D','D','D','D','D','D')
target <- c('A1', 'A2', 'A3','A4','A5','A6','A7','A8','A9','A10','A11','A12','A13','A14','A15','A16','A17','A18','A19','A20')
df <- data.frame(source, target)
```

We are trying to figure out which target is more likely to deliver on the source. The dataframe below shows the historical data of which targets delivered on what sources. I want to use neural networks to predict which target is more likely to buy on the source. This is reproducible as well.

```
   source target
1       A     A1
2       B     A2
3       C     A3
4       C     A4
5       D     A5
6       D     A6
7       D     A7
8       D     A8
9       D     A9
10      D    A10
11      D    A11
12      D    A12
13      D    A13
14      D    A14
15      D    A15
16      D    A16
17      D    A17
18      D    A18
19      D    A19
20      D    A20
```

This dataset is a subset of 415 datapoints.

The first thing I did was use the `class.ind` to transform the categorical variables into dummy variables. And then from there I am creating a neural network model that will help predict the target.

```
trainData <- cbind(class.ind(df$source)
trainData <- as.data.frame(trainData)
trainData2 <- cbind(trainData, df$target)
size <- length(unique(trainData2$`df$target`))
m1 <- nnet(`df$target` ~., trainData2, size=size, MaxNWts=10000)
```

1) How do I predict with this example?

2) How do I reproduce this with the neuralnet package?

3) I want to be able to use the parameters such as learning rate, etc. and can't seem to find that in the nnet package so that I can modify everything later.

Any guidance  would be really helpful!